# Extjs and Spring 4

Tags: extjs, spring-4

I'm getting an error while integrating spring and extjs. It's just simple code of a login page.

Error details are as follows

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)  ext-all.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'isProvider' of undefined

with the warning

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/LoginExt_Spring_20-06/services/api.js] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'services'

```js
//This is my controller code

Ext.define('myapp.controller.LoginController',{
  extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
  stores:['LoginStore'],
  Views:['LoginView','HomeView'],
  refs:[
        { ref:'loginview'},
        {ref:'homepage'}
        ],
   init:function(){
    this.control({
     'loginview button[action=login]':{
      click:'onLogin'
     },
     'loginview button[action=cancel]':{
      click:'onCancel'
     }
    });
   },
  onLogin:function(button){
   var loginForm=button.up('form[name=loginview]');
   var loginValues=loginForm.getValues();
   var login=loginForm.up('container[name=viewport]');
   var home=login.down('grid[name=homepage]');
   //console.log('loginValues are: '+loginValues.username);
   formController.authenticate(loginValues);
   //if(loginValues.username=='admin'&&loginValues.password=='password'){
    Ext.Msg.alert('status','successfull login');
    loginForm.setVisible(false);
    home.setVisible(true);
   //}else Ext.Msg.alert('status','Invalid credentials...');
  },
  
  onCancel:function(){
   var loginForm=button.up('form[name=loginview]');
   this.loginForm.getForm().reset();
  }
 });


//code in Store

Ext.define('myapp.store.LoginStore',{
  extend:'Ext.data.Store',
  model:'myapp.model.LoginModel',
  autoLoad:true,
  proxy:{
   type:'direct',
   directfn:formController.authenticate,
   reader:{
    type:'json'
   }
  }
   });

// I included 

Ext.require('Ext.direct.*', function() {
 Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
});
```

```html
index.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Jsp page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/extjs/ext-all.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="services/api.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/script/app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
  
  
  Application Initializer
  
  import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  context.register(ApplicationConfig.class);
  context.setServletContext(container);
  
  ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet=container.addServlet("Dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
  servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  servlet.addMapping("/services/*");
 }

}
  
  Java Controller
  
  
 @ExtDirectMethod
 public String authenticate(@RequestParam Login cred){
  
  loginDao.userCredentials(cred);
  return "HomeView";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the servlet mapping in web.xml